# React Native app won't run on real android phone

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run a React Native application on my physical device. This image shows up and I have been unable to find any help in regard to this issue.

[image]

Comment: It seems it is a compile-time error. Check the node server cmd line window, you might see the error there.

Comment: How do you run your app? Is it working in your emulator?

Comment: No error appears in Node. In fact it says that Bundle and Delta were at 100%. I run the app with react-native run-android. An emulator won't work either but I believe this is due to insufficient RAM.